# How to freeze css grid column widths after initial display

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, css-grid

I'm using CSS Grid to display a table of records. Each column is defined as "auto" because I'd like the column widths to fit the content.

In my app I have a button to fetch the next page of results, and I dynamically repopulate the grid from page 2 of the results. This has the effect of making the grid jump, because, of course, the content of each column on page 2 is not the same as it was on page 1. (I'm populating the table using Vue in a v-for loop.)

Is there any way to freeze the width of the columns after they are initially populated?

The only method I can think of is to use Javascript to get the widths of each column and then rewrite the CSS `grid-template-columns` value to specify columns as fixed-width. This is possible, but it feels like a kludge.

Maybe there's some CSS magic I don't know about? Something `position: sticky`, but for column widths?